# How to setup PhpStorm to debug OctoberCMS

Tags: phpstorm, octobercms

I have tried debugbar, but this does not give me enough information.

I have also tried setting up OctoberCMS using that same method to debug as I would with Laravel, but when I set a break point it stops at `index.php`. Also, I have tried the validation script inside PhpStorm, but it gives a 404 error.

I am trying to debug a plugin that I am developing, and it would be easier using an IDE like PhpStorm or NetBeans. Any help would be appreciated.

I have setup phpstorm to debug a laravel project by setting the URL:/phpstorm/public in the PHP Web Page settings but when I try some thing simular in my octobercms project all I get is waiting for connection meaning that the break point never gets hit here are the setting I am using

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port= 9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp/"
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

in the  PHP Web page I have

start URL:   `/octobercms/backend/rainlab/blog/Posts`
I have not set path mappings in the server as did not do this for the Laravel project I am using WAMP64 with the following settings `c:/wamp64/www/octobercms/`
and this is my vitrual host file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName octobercms.test
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/octobercms"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/octobercms">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

any advise on the setting I should use for Octobercms would be helpful

Comment: I have noticed that phpstorm stops on line 18 on index.php regardless of where I place a break point is there anyway of changing this

Comment: *"...but when I set a break point it stops at index.php"* Could be missing or wrong path mappings etc. Plus, it depends what code you are trying to debug. Actual plugin (that contains PHP code only) should be OK to debug, but a theme file (that contains mix of Twig, PHP and config) may not be (a special file format, CMS must be processing it differently). In any case: try placing `xdebug_break();` in your code (programmatic breakpoint) and see how it will behave.

Comment: Just to check I have wamp installed on c:\ and project installed on g:\ I have not ticked the use path mappings so when I do I have g:\wamp\website  and for the absolute path I have c:\wamp64\www\website  is that correct as I have tried xdebug_break(); but have to press step over several times before hitting the break point

Comment: Please describe this in more details. C:\wamp and G:\wamp are just copies or symlinked folders? Check out also suggestions at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html

Comment: Just copies phpstome allows me to debug but stops at index.php and not the desired breakpoint I can step through the code but its a little long winded I have read that when phpstorm ask to amend path mapping just click on the link and phpstorm will sort it out just going to try that out now

Comment: Now I get waiting for connectoin when I fill out the path mappings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this helps but after several attemps to get this to work I managed to get phpstorm to stop at the breakpoint I selected by the following

1. Set up wamp up as above
2. In the PHP Web Page section I set the Start URL: to
   /octobercms/backend/rainlab/blog/posts and apply settings
3. Set a break point in Posts.php
4. pressed the run button

and all is well with the world, I can now try to figure out why my plugin is not doing what its supposed to.